# How to import an R function from another package such that it would be available for the user?

Tags: r, package, devtools

I am writing a R package and I want to import generic function `forecast` from the package **forecast**. My package provides the method `forecast.myobj`. I have the  `forecast` in the `Imports:` in the package `DESCRIPTION` file and my function definition is as following:

```
##' @export
forecast.myobj <- function(x) {

}
```

I am using **devtools**  package (version 1.5) to build the package. The generated `NAMESPACE` has the following

```
S3method(forecast, myobj)
importFrom(forecast, forecast)
```

However when I load my package in a clean R session, function `forecast` is not available. Interestingly though I can see help pages of `forecast` and `forecast.myobj` and I can access these functions via `forecast::forecast` and `mypackage:::forecast.myobj`. Is it possible somehow to make `forecast` available to the user without depending on the package `forecast`? I checked documentation and reviewed a bunch of similar questions here, but I did not find the definite negative or positive answer.

Comment: Note that `devtools` uses `roxygen2` to generate the `NAMESPACE` file, so looking at that documentation may also help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The imported function must be exported in the NAMESPACE file for it to be available to users:

```
S3method(forecat, myobj)
importFrom(forecast, forecast)
export(forecast)
```

For an example, see the dplyr package's [NAMESPACE file](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/NAMESPACE) which imports `%>%` from the magrittr package and exports it so that it is accessible by the user.

Answer (score 12):

Giving my own answer to add information how to achieve the `NAMESPACE` described in @G. Grothendieck's answer using **devtools** package. The following lines (modeled after [dplyr's code](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/7bb56529ca3833f9739f4021ae2778610597bd34/R/tibble-reexport.r#L3))  do the trick

```
##' @importFrom forecast forecast
##' @name forecast
##' @rdname forecast.myobj
##' @export
NULL
```

Comment: Dead link, suggest something like https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/7bb56529ca3833f9739f4021ae2778610597bd34/R/tibble-reexport.r#L3

Comment: The code you linked is simpler than what is written in your answer. Both approaches work for me.