# Libraries added in imports in a Package needed to be called separately later when using the package?

Tags: r, package

I have created a test package which depends on few other packages data.table, dplyr,knitr, stringr etc. And i have mentioned all those under imports. I am after installing this test package only calling library(test). Which is giving error with the functions from these package like %>% from dplyr and with other functions also.
How can we fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [S3methods in NAMESPACE not exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966169/s3methods-in-namespace-not-exported)

Comment: The correct duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561929/how-to-import-an-r-function-from-another-package-such-that-it-would-be-available

Comment: adding importfrom this solves my problem, but still I am wodering how S3 and S4 methods are exported

Comment: You export via `@export` but in most cases `devtools::document()` will add exports for you in the `NAMESPACE` file.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to import the entire package or the specific functions in NAMESPACE. It is preferable to use `importsFrom(pkg, func1, func2, etc.)` to reduce possible name collisions. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports